# How to write a basic try/except in a Django Generic Class View

Tags: django, django-views

I'd like to write an except clause that redirects the user if there isn't something in a queryset. Any suggestions welcome. I'm a Python noob, which I get is the issue here.

Here is my current code:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    try:
        var = Model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, done=False)
    except:
        pass

    return var
```

I want to do something like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    try:
        var = Model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, done=False)
    except:
        redirect('add_view')

    return var
```

Comment: Where does this function reside? Typically view functions that would return redirects are in `views.py` where you would use the form `get_queryset(request)` and not `get_queryset(self)` (unless it's a method of a class that does have access to `request`).

Comment: You might look at get-object-or-404 shortcuts: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/?from=olddocs#a-shortcut-get-object-or-404

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A try except block in the `get_queryset` method isn't really appropriate. Firstly, `Model.objects.filter()` won't raise an exception if the queryset is empty - it just returns an empty queryset. Secondly, the `get_queryset` method is meant to return a queryset, not an `HttpResponse`, so if you try to redirect inside that method, you'll run into problems.

I think you might find it easier to write a function based view. A first attempt might look like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    """
    Display all the objects belonging to the user 
    that are not done, or redirect if there are not any,
    """
    objects = Model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, done=False)
    if not objects:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/empty-queryset-url/")
    return render(request, 'myapp/template.html', {"objects": objects})
```

The advantage is that the flow of your function is pretty straight forward. This doesn't have as many features as the `ListView` generic class based view (it's missing pagination for example), but it is pretty clear to anyone reading your code what the view is doing.

If you really want to use the class based view, you have to dig into the [CBV documentation for multiple object mixins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/) and the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4/django/views/generic/list.py), and find a suitable method to override.

In this case, you'll find that the `ListView` behaviour is quite different to what you want, because it never redirects. It displays an empty page by default, or a 404 page if you set `allow_empty = False`. I think you would have to override the `get` method to look something like this (untested).

```
class MyView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, done=False)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()

        if len(self.object_list == 0):
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/empty-queryset-url/")
        context = self.get_context_data(object_list=self.object_list)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is purely supplemental to @Alasdair's answer. It should really be a comment, but couldn't be formatted properly that way. Instead of actually redefining `get` on the `ListView`, you could override simply with:

```
class MyView(ListView):
    allow_empty = False # Causes 404 to be raised if queryset is empty

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(MyView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except Http404:
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/empty-queryset-url/")
```

That way, you're not responsible for the entire implementation of `get`. If Django changes it in the future, you're still good to go.

Comment: This was the first implemention I considered! It's more DRY than my answer, but I decided against using it because you have to look at the docs or source code to understand when the 404 exception is raised, so it's a bit harder to understand. I think either approach is ok.

Comment: Yeah. This is actually one of the sticky points about CBVs in Django. If you need to do anything even a little complicated, you're suddenly rewriting the guts of the CBV. Really, in this case it's only lucky that the view is already set up to allow raising a 404 if the queryset is empty, otherwise, you wouldn't even have a choice but to rewrite the entire `get` method.